# Инспекция кода: Реализация GET запроса в Django REST Framework

Tags: django, инспекция-кода, django-rest-framework

Учусь писать "красивый" хорошо читаемый и технологичный код. По этому буду рад комментариям и по оформлению в том числе.

**Задача:**
По тз аутентифицированному клиенту должны возвращаться n-ные поля моделей.

Если запрос приходит без PrimaryKey
**url**`path('users/', ...` т.е. *GET [http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/*,\](http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/*,%5C)
то рендерятся поля всех моделей из бд.

Если же *РК* был передан и он существует,
**url** `path('users/<str:pk>/, ...'` т.е. *GET [http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/2*\](http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/2*%5C)
то отдается конкретная модель, иначе клиент получает сообщение о несуществующем ключе

**Вопросы:**

1. На сколько такой способ корректен(использовать одну функцию для двух, пусть похожих, но но все же разных GET-запросов)?
2. На сколько читабельна такая конструкция *try-except*, на сколько она корректно составлена?
3. Как в целом выглядит этот код?

```
**views.py**

class UserViewSet(ListAPIView):

    # Allow only authenticated users to access this urls
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        '''
        Handles `CustomUser` objects into JSON and sends to the client.
        -If function did not recieve primary_key into **kwargs, it serializes fields of all CustomUser models.
        -If function recieved primary_key and it is exists, then serializes this model, otherwise tells that primary_key recived does not exists.
        '''

        try:
            pk = kwargs['pk']
            try:
                queryset = CustomUser.objects.get(id=pk)
            except:
                return Response({
                        "message": f"User with primary_key `{pk}`does not exists."},
                        status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
                    )
        except:
            queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
            serializer = ReadOnlyUserSerializer(queryset.values(), many=True)
        else:
            serializer = ReadOnlyUserSerializer(queryset, many=False)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как по мне то `ListAPIView` не совсем подходит для отображения конкретной модели.
Советую вам глянуть в сторону `ModelViewSet`. Этот класс подойдет для чтения, создания, обновления и удаления объекта. Он так же поддерживает возможности  схожие с `ListAPIView` для отображения списка объектов.

Код выглядит довольно кратко

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.router import SimpleRouter
from ... import ваш сериализатор

class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]  # Эту часть можно упустить если в settings.py указать настройку для DRF
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ваш сериализатор

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if request.action in ('list', 'retrieve'):
            return ReadOnlyUserSerializer
        return WriteOnlyUserSerializer

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Если вам нужно реализовать только чтение то можно заменить `ModelViewSet` на `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! ReadOnly боюсь не подойдет, дело в том что мой UserViewSet содержит в себе весь CRUD функционал **(GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE)** , работает с двумя сериалайзерами _ReadOnlyUserSerializer_ и _WriteOnlyUserSerialize_. Полагаю, что с точки зрения архитектуры это не правильно, и viewset-ы тоже должны быть разведены на два Read и Write класса, но не могу понять как правильно прикрутить два разных класса к одному и тому же урлу, так как по ТЗ, например **GET** и **POST** должны работать с `path('users/'` , и **GET(pk), PUT, PATCH, DELETE** с `path('users/<str:pk>/`  .

Comment: Еще не успел с этим поэкспериментировать, возможно все просто, но в голове этой картины пока не вижу, так что буду благодарен за совет. Сейчас урлы работают через _path('',...)_  , вероятно нужно переделывать на _router-ы_

Comment: `urlpatterns = [path('users/api-token-auth/', LoginAPIView.as_view(), name='api-token-auth'), path('users/<str:pk>/', UserViewSet.as_view(), name='users_edit'), path('users/', UserViewSet.as_view(), name='users'),
]`

Comment: Вам не нужно использовать 2 разных урл если вы хотите использовать разные сериализаторы. Вы можете их переопределить переписав метод `get_serializer_class`

Comment: @Py_DG чуть дополнил ответ

Comment: Не очень понял, для чего мне использовать `get_serializer_class` если нужный сериализатор определен в каждом методе, т.е. в `def get(...): есть serializer = ReadOnlyUserSerializer(...)` , а в `def post(...): есть serializer = RegistrationSerializer(...) #для POST сер-зер отдельный так как там вызывается метод models.CustomUser.create_user() где генерится токен и тд ` , в `def patch(...): есть serializer = WriteOnlyUserSerializer(...)`

Comment: вопрос как использовать 2 разных ViewSet с одним и тем же урлом. или это вообще не нужно делать и можно оставить один ViewSet и для запросов чтения и запросов записи

Comment: @Py_DG да, всё делается через один ViewSet

Comment: Супер, спасибо!

Comment: @Py_DG Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.

Comment: Поставил. я задал еще один вопрос по той же теме. Так что если есть желание проходите по :https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1218144/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-put-%d0%b8-patch-%d0%b2-django-rest-framework